# carrier infinity 96 furnace extended exterior exhaust concerns

Tags: exterior, freezing, extension, exhaust

Due to severe wind and drifting snow that has blocked my furnace exhaust pipe I have extended the exterior intake and exhaust pipes approximately 8 ft up. The exhaust right angles out below my eaves and gutter.  I have installed a high grade heat cable around the exterior pipe and covered the pipe with insulation and then a vinyl type wrap over the insulation. This is supposed to keep the moisture from freezing in both the vertical pipe as well as the horizontal pipe between my inside floor joists.

However, I am concerned that due to the length of the extension that there may still be freezing in the exhaust line. Any ideas how to confirm short of an ice block shutting down my furnace? Am I missing something in my solution to this problem? Have I created other problems?

In the past I have religiously shoveled any drift in the area of the exhaust but if I am away from my home for an extended time and the furnace shuts down it will create major freezing problems and damage within my home.

Comment: Good question!  Mind posting a photo of the outdoor exhaust arrangement to help us get a better image of what you did?

Comment: I will see if I can get a picture that will show the configuration.  Since it has the vinyl wrap and the pipe is close to the exterior wall of the house,it may be difficult to actually see what i have done except for the extended piping.